# Methods in extended class are not working

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity, slidingdrawer

I created a menu, where you can swipe up and down. I created this menu as another `activity`. Now, I need this menu to be added to on other `activities`.

Following is the code of my menu(SlidingDrawer)

**Java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DropDownMenu extends Activity {

    private TextView addInquiry, addEvent, additionalInfo, addToContacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drop_down_menu);

        //Intializing instance variables
        addInquiry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_add_inquiry);
        addEvent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_add_event);
        additionalInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_additional_info);
        addToContacts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_add_to_contacts);

        //Register the Listeners
        addInquiry.setOnClickListener(new AddInquiryEvent());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drop_down_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Test Button
    private class AddInquiryEvent implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(DropDownMenu.this,NewLead.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/slideButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" >
        </Button>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:background="#cbcbcc" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_add_inquiry"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/add_inquiry" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />




        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the Code of the other `activity`

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sales_inqury_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SalesInqury" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/sales_inqury"
        android:textSize="40sp" />


        <include layout = "@layout/activity_drop_down_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SalesInqury extends DropDownMenu {

    private ImageView addNewSalesInqury;
    private RelativeLayout salesInquryMainLayout;
    private TextView testEditSales;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales_inqury);

        //Intializing instance variables
        addNewSalesInqury = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.add_new_sales_inqury_btn);
        salesInquryMainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sales_inqury_main_layout);
        testEditSales = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testWord);



    }
}
```

But, there is an issue. Even thougn I can open the menu in this other activity, I can't click on it's Buttons (TextViews) and navigate to other activities. Why is this?

Comment: When you say _"I can open the menu"_, are you referring to `onCreateOptionsMenu` or `menu_add_inquiry`, `menu_add_event` etc. in the `OnCreate` of base activity?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare: What I meant is, I can open the menu (the slidingDrawer) which I created as another activity. It is included into this activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because after you've set a contentView in your `DropDownMenu` activity and bound the listener to the button, in `SalesInquiry` you set a different contentView. Although this includes the menu-layout, the Views are created anew, so there's no Listener bound to the button anymore.

A solution would either be to specify the menu callbacks in the layout xml via `android:onClick="..."` or by having a separate method in `DropDownMenu` that adds the Listener and that you call from your `SalesInquiry` class *after* setting the content view.

**Example 1, specifying callback in XML**

Add `android:onClick="onMenuItemClicked"` to menu item `TextView`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_add_inquiry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/add_inquiry" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onMenuItemClicked"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

Add this method to `DropDownMenu` class and remove the `AddInquiryEvent` class and the registering of the listeners.

```
public void onMenuItemClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.menu_add_inquiry:
        Intent intent = new Intent(DropDownMenu.this,NewLead.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.menu_other:
        // handle other menu item
        break;
    // ... and so on ...
    default:;
    }
}
```

**Example 2, bind listeners in a separate method**

In `DropDownMenu` move the registering of the Listeners to a separate method:

```
protected void registerListeners() {
    //Register the Listeners
    findViewById(R.id.menu_add_inquiry).setOnClickListener(new AddInquiryEvent());
}
```

Note, that you have to find the view again, as the one kept in the local variable is the wrong one, after `SalesInquiry` set it's content view.

Call the method in SalesInquiry after setting the content view.

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales_inqury);
  registerListeners();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please be kind enough to write a small code example?

Comment: Added example for callback,

Comment: Added example for adding listeners in separate method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attaching the listener to `addInquiry` in the `DropDownMenu`:

```
//Register the Listeners
addInquiry.setOnClickListener(new AddInquiryEvent());
```

This listener is not attached to the `TextView` in the extended class, since the `setContentView` is called and layout is refreshed.

Possible solution, if you are not using the `DropDownMenu` activity on its own then simply (remove setContentView):

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //in DropDownMenu
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_drop_down_menu);
...
...
```

Not the best solution but would work.

**Update: Better Solution**
(1) Let the subclass decide which layout to show. This layout must contain the menu (which is true in your case).

```
public class DropDownMenu extends Activity {

    private TextView addInquiry, addEvent, additionalInfo, addToContacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _setContentView();

        //Intializing instance variables
        addInquiry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_add_inquiry);
        addEvent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_add_event);
        additionalInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_additional_info);
        addToContacts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_add_to_contacts);

        //Register the Listeners
        addInquiry.setOnClickListener(new AddInquiryEvent());
    }

    protected void _setContentView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drop_down_menu);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

`@override` the `_setContentView` method so that we do not set the view twice.

```
public class SalesInqury extends DropDownMenu {

    ...
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        //Intializing instance variables
        addNewSalesInqury = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.add_new_sales_inqury_btn);
        salesInquryMainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sales_inqury_main_layout);
        testEditSales = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testWord);
    }

    @Override
    protected void _setContentView() {
        // need to make sure this layout contains the menu (otherwise NullPointerException may arise)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales_inqury); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If this works, let me know. I will post a better solution.. need to make sure the problem is what I think..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. but can you please try with extending the DropDownMenu-Activity instead of Activity.

```
 public class NewActivity extends DropDownMenu {
 // override which you want to override 
}
```

And make sure DropDownMenu in such a way that you can extends  what you want to implements. Hope you have got my point.

Comment: Then you need to use Fragmented Activity. and update the fragment accordingly.. take look on this app - https://github.com/Michenux/YourAppIdea/tree/master/YourAppIdea

Answer (score 0):

### Consistency Issue (Recommendation)

There is a **HUGE** misnomer in your class name, you should **NOT** call an Activity DropDownMenu.
This is confusing, you should instead call it DropDownActivity or something like that. Also do  you really need to use an Activity? You do realize a View can still listen to the click of a button right? Not only an Activity can listen to button clicks. If you encapsulate all of this in a View and have a dedicated listener for that view, then you wouldn't have any need for another Activity.

### Possible Solution

It's likely related to the activity/component you have registered to listen to the buttons is not correct. Validate your code so that you can at least get the correct response of the onClick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Listeners are bound to the correct buttons

Comment: Activity is not mandatory. I need a way to write my menu code "once", only "once".

Comment: "There is a HUGE misnomer in your class name, you should NOT call an Activity DropDownMenu. This is confusing, you should instead call it DropDownActivity or something like that. Also do you really need to use an Activity? You do realize a View can still listen to the click of a button right? Not only an Activity can listen to button clicks. If you encapsulate all of this in a View and have a dedicated listener for that view, then you wouldn't have any need for another Activity."

I have never done this. How?

Comment: Then you best option is to just create a View with my recommendation, its far simpler and far more effective.

Comment: How? specially, then how can I "create one code" for it, rather than calling the intialiazing and recreating all the methods inside every activity?

Comment: What does "create one code" mean? Do you mean execute only one and use for the rest of the lifecycle of ALL your activities? or do you mean something else?

Comment: What I meant is, Now, I create buttons in this "view". Those buttons should perform something. There should be only one button code. Otherwise, I have to include the XML file to the other activities, and create these button actions in each and every activity. Rather than that, what I need to do is, Create one xml file (View), create a class which can deal with the buttons in that XML, and use that class everywhere